# Qt - keypressevent not triggered when combo-box active

Tags: qt, pyqt

When i enter the **keypressevent** while pressing on a **combobox**, keypressevent is not triggered. Is there a way to still get events, when another widget is active?

```
def keyPressEvent(self, event):
    if event.key() == 49: #49 = number 1 on keyboard
        self.takeScreenshot()
```

**Eventfilter**:

```
def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
    if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress:
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_Delete:
            print datetime.datetime.now().time()

    return QtGui.QWidget.eventFilter(self, obj, event)
```

even using eventFilter, when i am clicking on a combobox, the event is not propagated to this function.

Answer (score 4):

It's a [C++ example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/eventsandfilters.html) but I think you will find the same for Python:

> Sometimes an object needs to look at, and possibly intercept, the events that are delivered to another object. For example, dialogs commonly want to filter key presses for some widgets; for example, to modify Return-key handling.

```
bool FilterObject::eventFilter( QObject* object, QEvent* event )
{
    if ( ( object == target ) && ( event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress ) )
    {
        QKeyEvent* keyEvent = static_cast< QKeyEvent* >( event );
        if (keyEvent->key() == 49) // Better to use Qt::Key_*
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

So I suggest you to use the `eventFilter( ... )`.

Comment: Thanks! I will give it a try tomorrow! and let you know

Comment: I gave it a try, with the code i've edited into my question, still, when i click on a widget, even the eventfilter is not getting it.

Comment: Have you called the [`installEventFilter`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qobject.html#installEventFilter) function ? Search for it in the linked example.

Comment: Its working all the time, but when i click on a combobox and want to chage the state, while the combobox menu is open, other key events are not triggered.

Comment: This does not solve the problem. Its also not working for me

Comment: This worked for me, specifically for comboboxes, and in C++ (with Qt5). You do need to remember to use installEventListener (for each such component), and you need to handle your special case in the eventFilter code.